# Self Joining SQL Query with a Calculated Field (Using MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (tblMembers) that contains personal demographic information for plan members.  I need to find out if there are Employee ID's in the table that are assigned to more than one person.  I feel like there is an easy way to do this but I am struggling.  I attempting to create a self join query that joins the tblMembers on the Employee_ID field.  In that query I have a calculated field that concatenates the First and Last name of the member.  Below is what I have tried, there are no current fields that will distinguish each member (like SSN), thus I need to create a calculated field.  This SQL does not work as it is asking me for the values of AFirst and BFirst.  Also as a note I am writing this code in MS Access.

```
SELECT A.BENEFIT_PERIOD, 
A.BENEFIT_TYPE, 
A.PLAN_NAME, 
A.PERSON_TYPE, 
A.LAST_NAME, 
A.FIRST_NAME, 
A.MIDDLE_NAME, 
A.SUFFIX, 
A.MARITAL_STATUS, 
A.RETIRED, 
A.HOURS_WORKED, 
A.GENDER, 
A.COVERAGE, 
A,EMPLOYEE_ID
A.TOTAL_MONTHLY_COST, 
A.PENDING_STATUS, 
A.FIRST_NAME & A.LAST_NAME AS AFirstLast, 
B.FIRST_NAME & B.LAST_NAME AS BFirstLast
FROM [Benefit Detail Report] AS A INNER JOIN [Benefit Detail Report] AS B ON A.[EMPLOYEE_ID] = B.[EMPLOYEE_ID]
WHERE AFirstLast <> BFirstLast;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `WHERE` clause with a join, you should just repeat the calculation:

```
WHERE (A.FIRST_NAME & A.LAST_NAME) <> (B.FIRST_NAME & B.LAST_NAME)
```

Also, you've got multiple typographical errors:

`A,EMPLOYEE_ID` has a comma that should be a dot, and is missing a comma at the end (should be `A.EMPLOYEE_ID,`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias in the `WHERE` clause. In fact, i don't see any need to use the `WHERE` clause. You can use this :

```
SELECT A.BENEFIT_PERIOD, 
A.BENEFIT_TYPE, 
A.PLAN_NAME, 
A.PERSON_TYPE, 
A.LAST_NAME, 
A.FIRST_NAME, 
A.MIDDLE_NAME, 
A.SUFFIX, 
A.MARITAL_STATUS, 
A.RETIRED, 
A.HOURS_WORKED, 
A.GENDER, 
A.COVERAGE, 
A.EMPLOYEE_ID
A.TOTAL_MONTHLY_COST, 
A.PENDING_STATUS, 
A.FIRST_NAME & A.LAST_NAME AS AFirstLast, 
B.FIRST_NAME & B.LAST_NAME AS BFirstLast
FROM [Benefit Detail Report] AS A INNER JOIN [Benefit Detail Report] AS B ON A.[EMPLOYEE_ID] = B.[EMPLOYEE_ID]
and (A.FIRST_NAME <> B.FIRST_NAME or A.LAST_NAME <> B.LAST_NAME);
```

Comment: Note that your SQL returns different results: the query that OP posted would allow for someone to have the same last name, but a different first name, or a different first name, and the same last name (e.g. John Doe and Jane Doe). Yours doesn't. The WHERE statement IS needed.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - Good point, i corrected the query, but i still think there is no need of `WHERE` clause!